# MATLAB: Using 'connect' command to simplify MIMO model

Tags: matlab, control-theory, linear-control

Consider the 3x3 MIMO model [P_sys](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rV-27IBzC_s-A9g2Y858k6CQRyVG65h3/view?usp=sharing) with inputs and outputs as shown:

[MIMO System Representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X00Xb.png)

K is a PI controller that is used to stabilize the third output,i.e., loop 1 is closed first.

I wish to include the dynamics of the controller K in the reduced 2x2 MIMO model with inputs I_1,I_2 and outputs r_g,\nu

Please confirm if I have used the command connect properly in the code as follows:

```
load P_sys.mat
s = tf('s')
k_p = 1;
k_i = 18.8496;
K = k_p + k_i/s;
K.u = 'e_omega';
K.y = 'T_e';
Sum = sumblk('e_omega = omega_p_ref - \omega_p');
T = connect(P_sys,K,Sum,{'I_1','I_2','omega_p_ref'},{'r_g','\nu'});
```

I understand that T is now a 3x2 system, but if I simply ignore the input 'omega_p_ref', I end up with a 2x2 system

Someone who has experience of using this command, please confirm if what I have done is correct.

Thanks a bunch!

Edit: Added the P_sys state space information below for convenience

```
A = [-10.1743147787628  6.33848393443564    2.83053960557233e-05    -2.00486274008812e-05   0.0101156376822215;
-9.16775143671759   0.627823658752316   1.98137772390063e-05    -1.75443812073728e-05   0.00634588061855046;
783220167.460741    -487937375.295125   -2182.46555386313   1545.34164838041    -778703.196403871;
-1627527900.69975   1013931618.56602    4535.35552271822    -3877.96970385813   4820427.94201476;
-404.660712284203   -722.474615698841   0   -0.000665806346950841   -0.139419875340118];

B = [0  0   0;
0   0   0.0220422852001799;
127095767.644570    0   0;
-477713516.049144   2383781669.12079    0;
0   0   4.27350427350427];

C = [1  0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   1];    

D = 0;

P_sys = ss(A,B,C,D);

P_sys.Inputname = {'I_1','I_2','T_e'};
P_sys.Outputname = {'r_g','\nu','\omega_p'};
P_sys.Statename = {'r_g','\nu','p_p','p_s','\omega_p'};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "ignore the input"? If it doesn't matter, why not remove it entirely? Also, could you add P_sys directly in the code?

Comment: @SampleTime I mean to say that at some particular value of omega_p_ref I can focus on the 2x2 system. I cannot ignore the dynamics completely since the states 'r_g' and 'nu' depend on the value of omega_p. Also, I have now added the state space data in the question itself.

Comment: I didn't meant to ignore the dynamics, but remove the input, i.e. setting $T_e = -K \omega_p$ which would imply $\omega_{p,ref} = 0$. However, your plant seems to be wrong, as it has only 2 inputs and 2 outputs. In your description and your picture, your plant has 3 inputs and 3  outputs, so there seems to be something wrong (setting `P_sys.Inputname = {'I_1','I_2','T_e'};` also gives an error because to this).

Comment: Also, two more things: First, you mentioned stabilizing the third output, but the system matrix you posted is already stable. Second, your image shows the inputs in the order $T_e, I_1, I_2$, while order of the plant input names in your code are $I_1, I_2, T_e$. Similar for the output names. You probably should double check that everything is defined in the correct order there and that the system matrices are correct.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the errors. My apologies. Some days are long. I think it is all correct now. I will try ignoring $\omega_{p,ref}$ (or setting it to zero) and see what happens. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Don't worry, no need to apologize. I posted an answer so you can see what I meant with omitting that specific input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to omit $\omega_{p,ref}$ as follows:

```
s = tf('s');
k_p = 1;
k_i = 18.8496;
K = -(k_p + k_i/s); % Note the minus here
K.u = '\omega_p'; % Input is now only \omega_p
K.y = 'T_e';
T = connect(P_sys, K, {'I_1', 'I_2'}, {'r_g', '\nu'}); % No more Sum needed here
```

This will give you a closed loop system with 2 inputs and 2 outputs.

If that is suitable for your needs depends of course on what you are trying to achieve. If you want to keep the third input, your code should be fine (assuming the order of the inputs/outputs is correct as well as the system matrices).

Comment: Thanks, this solves my problem. Also if I include the summing block and simply take $e_{\omega_p} = -\omega_p$, I get the same result, naturally.